# Grails 2.0: Conditionally instantiate a service

Tags: grails, service, noclassdeffounderror, grails-2.0

In my Grails application I have a service using a library with the 'provided' scope which is not shipped with the application.  In fact, there's no guarantee that is will ever be there because the customer has to buy it and if they decide not to, the app has a fall-back.

When doing run-app I still receive a `NoClassDefFoundError` for a class of that library even tough no code of the service is executed.

It's seems Grails is trying to compile the class. How can I prevent that?

Kind Regards

Jonas